# I want to run report(.html file) of protractor-html-reportor

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

I am doing end-2-end testing with protractor. and for creating a report of all these test cases, I am using Protractor-html-reportor, Which create an .html file as report of all these test cases. All is good. What I want that after creating that html file(Report), At the end I want to run it automatically on browser. Thanks in Advance?

Comment: Do you mean, launch the HTML report in a browser?

Comment: Yes, [Barney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6304906/barney), I want that. I have got solution. I have posted answer below. But it is having some warning issue. If you have some alternate way, then you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer from [sqa.stackexchange site](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29327/i-want-to-run-report-html-file-of-protractor-html-reportor).
I have used grunt-open for it. It is working fine. But it have following warning every time, when it launch report.
The warning is [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048138/in-grunt-open-configuration-it-cant-find-google-chrome). I have not got any solution so far. But it is working fine, if you dont worry about that warning.